# Including the contents of a javascript file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

If there a way to include the content of a javascript file into a Rails view?

I know about Ruby's File.read, but I'm searching for some helper already done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
  <%= render :file => '/path/to/rails/app/path/to/javascript.js' %>
<% end %>
```

So you can include any javascript code located on your machine. But to be honest there's [more appropriate way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602147/javascript-file-per-view-in-rails) to do that kind of things.