# How can I only show the JavaScript in particular controller and method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I have many models.  Now I like to show the JavaScript to only the particular controller and method.

For example, if I had code like this and want to show it only in **communities/show**
Should I paste this in the head of view/communities/show.html.erb?
or is there smarter way to manage this kind of things?
Obviously it looks ugly if I put it in the head of show file because JavaScript always should be placed within **< head>** tag.

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        refreshPartial();
        setInterval(refreshPartial, 5000)
    });


    function refreshPartial() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "<%= community_path %>/refresh_part",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "script",
      });
    }
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**communities.js**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  refreshPartial();
  setInterval(refreshPartial, 5000)
});


function refreshPartial() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "community/refresh_part",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "script",
  });
}
```

**view/communities/show.html.erb**

```
<%- content_for(:head) do -%>
<%= javascript_include_tag :communities.js -%>
<%- end -%>
```

**communities_layout**

```
<head>
<title>Merry Christmas!</title>
<%= yield(:head) -%>
</head>
```

Comment: this is the most cleaner way, and @MKK, you cannot use ruby variables with .js file, but you could use ruby variables will coffscript

Comment: Just changing communities.js to communities.js.coffee will be fine?

Comment: I have updated it. yes we can use it with coffscript; here we can specify URL as string..

Comment: I already had communities.js.coffee. I think it was automatically created by scaffolding. can I just copy and paste my JS code to there including ruby variable?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to do that

1. top of your show.html.erb:

   ```
   <% content_for :javascript_includes do %>
   <%= javascript_include_tag "forms.js" %>   
   <% end %>
   ```

   Also refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602147/javascript-file-per-view-in-rails)
2. [Where do you put page specific JavaScript code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167805/using-rails-3-1-where-do-you-put-your-page-specific-javascript-code?lq=1)  and take a look at [How Asset Pipeline works](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)