# RAILS 5 : Load Javascript per Controller

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Related to the same question ([Loading Javascript per controller in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23654254/loading-javascript-per-controller-in-rails))

I want to load a separated javascript file when this controller and one of its views is processed.

So I have some javascript code that works very well, but I want to outsource this code for the controller **orders_now**. So I paste this code into this file **app/assets/javascripts/orders_now.js** :

```
function request_loading_stations ()
{

$.ajax({
    method: "post",
    url: "/orders_now/search_for_loading_stations",

       data: { order_now_post: { loading_station_text_field: $('#loading_station_text_field').val() } }
    })
};
```

---

I did also an entry in **config/initializers/assets.rb** :

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( orders_now.js )
```

---

In the corresponding view I did the following entry to load the orders_now.js file.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag params[:controller] %>
```

---

Then I also restarted the Rails Web Server.

---

When I reload the Browser Page, the javascript file seems to be **not loaded**.

In the Browser Developer Tools I can see the javascript file is included:

```
<script src="/assets/orders_now.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1"></script>
```

But when I want to check the content of this file I see only:

```
(function() {


}).call(this);
```

What's going wrong ?

Comment: Could you share the orders_now.js ?

Comment: What is the name of your controller? Is it `OrdersNowController`?

Comment: yes, `OrdersNowController`

Answer (score 0):

I've found out that it works when I rename the `orders_now.js` to any other name, e.g. `orders_now_irgendwas.js`.

Also the entry `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( orders_now.js )`
is not necessary.

And `<%= javascript_include_tag params[:controller] %>`is also not necessary.

After renaming of `orders_now.js` the javascript function will always be loaded in the browser on each page request. For now it's ok for me.

Answer (score 0):

After you've run around the rabbit hole "As I Have"

The lightest approach to this issue is to load your js is via your layouts
See (Documents => rails => layouts)
Generally these control what is loaded and can be finetuned per action, method, controller

IE: `layout false {controller}`

```
class YOURController < ApplicationController
layout "mySpecialOrdersLayoutThatIncludesTheJSRequired", only: [:orders_now]
```

Or per controller action (method) in `orders_now` method:

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.html {render 'mySpecialOrdersLayoutThatIncludesTheJSRequired'}
end
```

Copy your current layout to `mySpecialOrdersLayoutThatIncludesTheJSRequired.html.erb` and include the necessary js in this file.

Hope this helps.