# Rails include js in html public files

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I have some html pages in which each page includes some javascripts files. Where I have to place this files?

```
folder/
  page1/
    index.html
    script1.js
  page2/
    index.html
    script2.js
```

> Updated

I explain better. I have some little projects composed by an html page and some javascripts files, in which i use a canvas. I have different scripts for each page.

```
/sketches
  /project1
     index.html
     script1.js
     sketch.js
  /project2
     index.html
     sketch.js
```

The files named 'sketch' are different between them. 
I tought to make one controller with a parameter id and basing on this I'll load a different project. I did it putting the html page inside the public folder and it worked, but I have problems with the javascripts, that are refused.

So, for what you are saying to me, I have to place all the javascripts in a separate folder... I'd like to keep that structure. Is there no way in rails to serve that folder, which contains all the projects,  as static?

Comment: Please accept answer if it is helpful to you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to place all js files under `app/assets/javascripts` folder.

> Updated Answer

Load the main JavaScript in application.js every time. Now create files for different needs. Create a form.js file, a myfancypart.js file etc. Don't load them in the application.html.erb layout. Load them dynamically when you need them:

application.html.erb:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
<%= yield :javascript_includes %>
```

top of your view.html.erb OR users/new.html.erb:

```
<% content_for :javascript_includes do %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "users_new.js" %>
<% end %>
```

Everything in the content_for block will be loaded at yield :javascript_includes.

Source: [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/602192)

Comment: The problem is that I need to distribute the javascripts files. Is it possible?
I have much pages and much javascripts to include, different in each page.
Is a mess for me to place all javascripts apart and include them in the pages, also beacause this javascripts files have some names equals

Comment: @GiuseppeMagazzù When you generate controller in rails , it will automatic   generate its js and css file, so you can add related js code to that js file for that controller's view.

Answer (score 2):

The best practice is to place all your third party assets in `vendor/assets` folder and your app specific assets in `app/assets` folder. And you should `require` the assets in their specific manifest files.
If your `vendor/assets/javascripts` folder have some js files like this,

```
`/vendor/
     /assets/
          /javascripts/`
               script1.js
               script2.js
```

Then in your `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` just add

```
  //= require script1
  //= require script2
```

In rails 5.1+, the `assets` directory is removed from vendor, so you should create your own directories and either add it to `config/initializers/assets.rb` to precompile or use relative path to the file with respect to vendor directory.

Answer (score 1):

You should follow like this:

```
folder/
  pages/
    index.html
    aboutus.html
  assets/
    js/
      some_js.js
      anoter_js.js
    css/
      homepage.css
      about.css
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/sketches
  sketch.js
  /project1
     index.html <-- include relative path for sketch.js
     script1.js
  /project2
     index.html <-- include relative path for sketch.js
```

I think u can just include relative path js file from your parent folder so u don't need to put to every subfolders.